# Follow Azure acklog item via HTTP Request

Tags: http, azure-devops

Is there a way to follow an Azure Backlog item or to add it into the list of the items I'm following via HTTP Request?

Here is the way I get all work items I'm following:
POST https://dev.azure.com/companyName/projectName/_apis/wit/wiql?api-version=5.1&Authorization=Basic BASE64PATSTRING

Body:
{
"query": "Select [System.Id], [System.WorkItemType] From WorkItems Where [System.Id] IN(@Follows)"
}

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can [follow the work item via REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/notification/subscriptions/create?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1#follow-a-work-item), a skeleton version looks like this:

API:

```
POST https://dev.azure.com/{org name} /_apis/notification/Subscriptions?api-version=5.1
```

Request body

```
{
  "filter": {
    "type": "Artifact",
    "artifactType": "WorkItem",
    "artifactId": "70"
  }
}
```

Note: artifactId is work item ID

Result:
[image]